# Search for missing files in folder

Tags: python, file

I have some folders which contains a lot of files. They are all build up like this:
Name-0000000000.txt
Name-0000000001.txt
Name-0000000002.txt
Name-0000000003.txt

and so on.

There can be 5000000 of files like this in a folder.
I want to know now how to find out if there is one or more files missing.

I would like to just check if one consecutive number is missing, but how. I know I can check for the first and last name in that folder:

```
import glob
import os
list_of_files = glob.glob('K:/path_to_files/*')
first_file = min(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(first_file)
print(latest_file)
```

But I have no clue how to find missing files :(

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why do you think that getting the max and min using `os.path.getctime` will work?

Comment: How does `getctime` give you the first and last? It gives the first and last ***updated***, not according to the name...

Comment: `os.path.isfile` could do the job, couldn't it?

Comment: You can isolate the number part of the names and have a simple list of ints. Then take the first and last, and do a set subtraction between the list and the range given by the first and last

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this code myself but something like this should work:

```
import glob
import os
list_of_files = glob.glob('K:/path_to_files/*')
first_file = min(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
for i in range(0,5000000): #Put the highest numbered file number here
   some_file = "Name-"+str(i).zfill(10)+".txt")

   if not some_file in list_of_files:
       print("file: "+some_file+" is not in the list.")
```

This code might need some minor adjustments to work for your specific case but it should be enough to guide you in the correct direction :)

Answer (score -1):

This solution only works if you know that there is only file missing.Take summation of all the file names (after removing the suffix and converting them to integers) and then subtract it from the expected sum. The result is the missing file name.

Comment: what if two or three files are missing? What would the result of substraction tell you then?

Comment: Yes then the above solution does not work. I specifically mentioned that the solution is only if there is one file missing.

Comment: so how the OP would know that only one file is missing and not two or three or more?